# Remove certain duplicate values from csv file

Tags: powershell, csv, powershell-3.0

I try to import a csv file  and create a xlsx file from the data afterwards. My Goal is to only show the value of Column1 once and not in every row. The csv file is already sorted so a check if the previous/next row has the same value would be possible.

**CSV**

```
"Column1";"Column2";"Column3"
"Value1A";"Value1B";"Value1C"
"Value1A";"Value2B";"Value2C"
"Value1A";"Value3B";"Value3C"
"Value2A";"Value4B";"Value4C"
```

**Expected Outcome**

```
"Column1";"Column2";"Column3"
"Value1A";"Value1B";"Value1C"
"";"Value2B";"Value2C"
"";"Value2B";"Value1C"
"Value2A";"Value4B";"Value4C"
```

**Outcome**

```
"Column1";"Column2";"Column3"
"Value1A";"Value1B";"Value1C"
"Value1A";"Value2B";"Value2C"
"Value1A";"Value2B";"Value1C"
"Value2A";"Value4B";"Value4C"
```

Only column1 duplicate cells should be empty.

**My Code to import and add to Excel**

```
$csv = "C:\path\to\file.csv"
$i = 1
Import-Csv $csv | Select-Object -Property Column1,Column2,Column3 | ForEach-Object {
  $j = 1
  foreach ($prop in $_.PSObject.Properties) {
    if ($i -eq 1) {
      $serverInfoSheet.Cells.Item($i, $j++).Value = $prop.Name
    } else {
      $serverInfoSheet.Cells.Item($i, $j++).Value = $prop.Value
    }
  }
  $i++
}
```

To provide further context imagine Column1 as a Date and Columns2 and 3 are Employees.

**Example of expected outcome**

```
"12/01/2020";"Mark";"Tony"
"";"Mark";"Andrew"
"";"Tony;Vanessa"
"12/02/2020";"Tony";"Michael"
```

I dont want the date to repeat 2 times because the excel sheet loses clear view.

Comment: $i starts out being 2. You then only increase it. How do you expect it to become 1, so it fires the if?

Comment: Yeah sorry, that was an error in the code

Comment: I don't understand 4th line in expected outcome: `"";"Value2B";"Value1C"`. Shouldn't it be `"";"Value3B";"Value3C"`?

Comment: I wanted to show that even if the values of Column2 or Column3 repeat they, will not be removed. Only Column1's value should be empty if it's the same value as before. I will add more context to the question.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve creates an unusable csv. WHY would you empty the column fields at all? After that sorting the excel by clicking on a column header will leave incomplete results..

Comment: We have a printable telephone excel list in our company and it looks a certain way for the last 20 years and the users want to have it EXACTLY as it is. That list was done manually over the last couple of years and I try to automate the process.
I'm aware that it's wrong to handle a .csv that way but it's just about the output and nothing but the excel file is done with the .csv. Thanks for mentioning it anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$Csv = @'
"Column1";"Column2";"Column3"
"Value1A";"Value1B";"Value1C"
"Value1A";"Value2B";"Value2C"
"Value1A";"Value3B";"Value3C"
"Value2A";"Value4B";"Value4C"
'@
```

```
$Csv | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ';' |
    Foreach-Object -Begin { $Last1 = $Null } {
        if ( $_.Column1 -eq $Last1 ) { $_.Column1 = '' }
        else { $Last1 = $_.Column1 }
        $_
    } | ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter ';'
```

```
"Column1";"Column2";"Column3"
"Value1A";"Value1B";"Value1C"
"";"Value2B";"Value2C"
"";"Value3B";"Value3C"
"Value2A";"Value4B";"Value4C"
```